# Using file test code to test for permissions, I have used -rwx inside [] but will not work?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, sudo

```
if [ -w  /etc/shadow ]

then 
  echo "You have the powers of the super user!" 

else
  echo "Wow we  probably have to try this again  logged as root" 
fi
```

I have logged in  as root  and the command still didn't work. File displays user permissions:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root shadow 1301 Jul  7 15:18 /etc/shadow
```

Comment: Should work - how exactly are you logged in as root?

Answer (score 0):

Your script works for me as you coded it.  Works fine as is but should start

```
#!/bin/bash
```

I created the file test.sh and pasted in your code.

```
chmod +x test.sh

./test.sh
```

Received the correct echo message depending on what privs I had when I executed the script.